# How to build VTK with CMake for parallel computing?

Tags: parallel-processing, cmake, codeblocks, vtk

I would like to build VTK with CMake for parallel computing, the environment is Win10 (x64), Codeblocks-12.11, VTK-7.0.0 and CMake-3.5.0. When I selected `VTK_Group_MPI` and `Module_vtkParallelMPI`, CMake errors are as follows. So how to build VTK with CMake for parallel computing? Thank you in advance!

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
MPI_C_LIBRARIES (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "vtkParallelMPI" in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/Parallel/MPI
    linked by target "vtkIOMPIImage" in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/MPIImage
    linked by target "vtkIOMPIParallel" in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/MPIParallel
    linked by target "vtkIOParallelNetCDF" in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/ParallelNetCDF
MPI_HEADER_PATH
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/Parallel/MPI
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/Parallel/MPI
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/Parallel/MPI
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/Parallel/MPI
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/Parallel/MPI
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/Parallel/MPI
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/Parallel/MPI
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/MPIImage
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/MPIImage
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/MPIImage
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/MPIImage
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/MPIImage
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/MPIImage
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/MPIImage
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/MPIParallel
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/MPIParallel
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/MPIParallel
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/MPIParallel
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/MPIParallel
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/MPIParallel
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/MPIParallel
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/ParallelNetCDF
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/ParallelNetCDF
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/ParallelNetCDF
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/ParallelNetCDF
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/ParallelNetCDF
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/ParallelNetCDF
   used as include directory in directory C:/VTK/source/VTK-7.0.0/IO/ParallelNetCDF
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that I haven't tried to build VTK myself, but I know enough CMake to see that it failed to find the MPI library, because the variables MPI_C_LIBRARIES and MPI_HEADER_PATH is not set.

How are you configuring CMake?

If you are using the CMake GUI - which I would recommend that you do - you ought to switch on *grouped* and *advanced* options.

Now, the Find_MPI CMake script uses the registry to find MPI libraries - so you can help it by setting the `MSMPI_BIN`environment variable.

See [Find_MPI Source code](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindMPI.cmake)

However, if all of that is too much black magic, then you can simply enter the correct values into CMake for the missing variables, provided that you have turned on advanced and grouped mode.

Answer (score 0):

Add your MPI binaries directory to your path.

```
PATH=$PATH:${YOU_MPI_DIRECTORY}/bin
```

MPI compilers, mpicc, mpicxx, mpif90, etc, are wrappers that should solve these dependencies.